# Welches ist das neutralste Verb für den Geschlechtsakt?

Tags: word-choice, verb

Es gibt wie in den meisten Sprachen auch im Deutschen eine Vielzahl von Synonymen für den Vollzug des Geschlechtsaktes.

### Verben

Einige der Synonyme sind metaphorisch umschreibend (*vögeln, rammeln, nageln, pudern, knallen, bürsten*) 
oder nur regional gebräuchlich (*pudern, schnackseln*), 
manche wirken ironisch (*poppen*) oder harmlos (*pimpern*), 
andere derb (*bumsen/bimsen*) bis vulgär (*ficken*) 
bzw. hochgestochen (*koitieren, kohabitieren, kopulieren*). 
Zum Teil funktionieren sie nur mit einem (meist mänlichen) Aktör (*beschlafen, flachlegen, vernaschen*), der (meist weibliche) Geschlechtspartner bleibt sprachlich inaktiv/passiv, 
zu einem anderen Teil sind sie reflexiv und nur im Plural gebräuchlich (*[Geschlechts-]Verkehr haben, verkehren*), 
andere sind (inzwischen) auf verschiedene Arten verwendbar (*jmd./miteinander ficken, bumsen, vögeln*). 
Einige Verben basieren auf fremden Substantiven (*koitieren < Koitus*) 
oder werden mit einer Vorsilbe aus einem Verb für eine andere Tätigkeit gebildet (*beschlafen*, nicht **beischlafen*), 
und daneben gibt es diverse meist verklemmt umschreibende Phrasen aus Substantiv und Verb (*Nummer schieben, Liebe machen, Sex / Geschlechtsverkehr / Beischlaf haben / machen / ausüben / vollführen, Ehe vollziehen, horizontal Tango tanzen*) 
oder Adjektiv und Verb (*intim werden, körperlich lieben*). 
Manche betonen den Zeugungszweck (*begatten*) 
oder soziale Konventionen (*ehelichen Pflichten nachkommen*). 
Einige sind sehr altmodisch (*(er-)kennen (im biblischen Sinne)*) 
oder heute völlig ungebräuchlich (*minnen, zwirnen*) 
und andere kommen nur (evtl. vorübergehend) in einer Subkultur vor (*klarmachen, knacken, knattern*?).

Interessanterweise gibt es abseits der Fachsprache kaum Fremdwörter (z.B. **sex(ier)en, *bängen, *shaggen*), allerdings sind einige Metaphern auch in anderen Sprachen üblich (*nageln ~ nail*), sodass es sich mitunter um Lehnübersetzungen in die eine oder andere Richtung handeln könnte.

### Frage

Welches Verb kann man verwenden, wenn man sich weder vulgär noch übertrieben gehoben ausdrücken möchte und keine mehrteilige Umschreibung verwenden will sowie bevorzugt ein „symmetrisches“ einvernehmliches Miteinander vermitteln möchte? 
Das heißt, welche der oben genannten (oder vergessenen) Alternativen ist im Allgemeinen am neutralsten – am wenigsten markiert?

### Beispiellückensätze

> ……… macht Spaß!
>   Lass uns ………!
>   Willst du ………?
>   ……… ihn doch! / doch mit ihm!
>   Er hat noch nie ……….
>   Sie ……… nur abends und nur im Bett.
>   In einer durchschnittlichen Beziehung wird *x*-mal pro Monat ……….

Comment: _Sex haben_ oder einfach _Sex_ lässt sich in die meisten dieser Lücken einbauen und ist IMHO ziemlich neutral und alltagstauglich - kommt aber nicht in Frage, weil Du unbedingt nach einem Verb suchst, wenn ich Dich richtig verstanden habe?

Comment: Ziemlich neutral und verbreitet ist _mit jemandem schlafen_ bzw. _miteinander schlafen_. Es ist aber auch mehrteilig und weniger geeignet, wenn keine zweite Person genannt werden kann, etwa in den beiden letzten Beispielsätzen.

Comment: Ja, @Matthias, es geht mir explizit um ein Verb. Ansonsten stimme ich dir und @ chirlu natürlich zu.

Comment: Ich bin nicht qualifiziert, diese Frage zu beantworten, aber ich möchte noch zwei Synonyme hinzufügen: "es tun" und "es machen". Beide sind meines Erachtens neutral, obwohl vielleicht nicht so eindeutig, weil sowohl "es" als auch "tun" und "machen" sehr allgemeine Worte sind.

Comment: Das Wort »budern« wird häufig (so auch hier) falsch geschrieben. Es hat nichts mit »pudern« (Puder auftragen) zu tun, sondern stammt von »buttern« ab. *Buttern* bedeutet Butter herstellen. In vielen alpinen Gegenden kommt der Rahm in ein Fass, das mit einem Deckel verschlossen wird. Der Deckel hat ein Loch, durch das der Butter-Stößel geführt wird. Diesen Stößel bewegt man so lange in schnellen Bewegungen ein und aus, bis aus dem Rahm Butter geworden ist. Da mal hier einen dicken Stab durch ein passendes Loch ein und aus bewegt, war es kein Wunder, dass mit »buttern« auch Sex bezeichnet wurde.

Comment: (Fortsetzung): In Österreich, wo »budern« entstanden ist, hier vor allem im Osten (Raum Wien) werden die harten Plosive p, t und k sehr häufig weich ausgesprochen (wie b, d und g) (In Wien sagt man zum Teppich »Deebich«). Und so wurde aus »buttern« »budern«. Nachdem der Ursprung des Wortes vergessen war, war aber auch unklar, ob das dialekthafte b vielleicht nicht doch ein hochsprachliches p sein sollte, und so entstand die Verwechslung mit »pudern«.

Comment: Sex haben ist mW auch ein Anglizismus

Comment: Sex ist nun mal eine schmutzige Sache, zumindest, wenn man es richtig macht. (W. Allen)

Comment: @FabioTurati: "Es tun" ist oberverklemmt. Fehlt nur noch dazu mit den Fingern Anführungsstriche in die Luft zu malen. Ich behaupte mal, es gibt kein neutrales Verb dafür.

Comment: Es gibt aus meiner Sicht kein einzeln gebrauchtes Verb im Deutschen. Ansonsten siehe oben @chirlus Kommentar.

Comment: Ich denke, am neutralsten ist "miteinander schlafen"

Comment: Niemand hat bisher »[erkennen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erkennen)« genannt ;-)

Comment: @dakab „_(er-)kennen (im biblischen Sinne)_“ steht in der Frage.

Comment: @Crissov: Oh, stimmt, hatte nur nach „erkennen“ gesucht; einfach nur „kennen“ hat nämlich nicht die Bedeutung, um die es hier geht.

Comment: 'herumsexen' oder 'rumsexen' scheint es auch zu geben

Comment: ich bin für 'sich paaren'

Comment: _Sex_ ist erst seit ein paar Jahrzehnten Bestandteil des deutschen Wortschatzes. Vielleicht entwickelt sich daraus doch noch *_sexen_ oder *_sexieren_. Vielleicht wird auch _ficken_ noch weiter entvulgarisiert. Derzeit lautet die Antwort auf meine Frage leider, dass es kein neutrales Verb gibt und der Grad an Angemessenheit sehr vom Kontext abhängt.

Comment: Die symmetrischste Formulierung, die ich kenne, die auch weder vulgär noch gehoben ist, wäre die Umschreibung “bei jemandem liegen”. Allerdings erfüllt sie  Ihre vermuteten Kriterien (spezifisches Verb für den Akt) nicht.

Comment: @Crissov Zu *sexen. Ich habe sexeln/sexln schon gelesen, allerdings im humoristischen Umfeld. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sexeln

Comment: @Crissov hier kommt es auch vor, (https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/2599-sexeln), allerdings nebst der erschreckenden Erklärung “ Hauptsächlich von älteren Swingerpaaren in Anzeigen gebraucht.“ Daher weiß ich nicht, ob es tatsächlich so unverfänglich ist, wie ich dachte.

Comment: Ich dachte immer *ins Bett gehen* sei ein neutraler Ausdruck dafür. Auch wenn es natürlich sprachlich schwierig wird, wenn als Ort mal nicht das Bett genutzt wird. "Komm, lass uns in der Küche ins Bett gehen." Hm...

Answer (score 2):

Auch wenn "Liebe machen" mehrteilig ist, glaube ich dennoch, dass es für den Anwendungsfall der am besten geeignete Ausdruck ist. "Liebe machen" verletzt nur diesen einen Constraint, da es

- weder vulgär noch übertrieben gehoben ausdrücken
- ein „symmetrisches“ einvernehmliches Miteinander vermittelt
- und allgemein gängig ist

Comment: "Liebe machen" finde ich durchaus verklemmten Sprachgebrauch. Miteinander zu schlafen hat mit Liebe oft nichts zu tun.

Comment: _Liebe machen_ wird wohl eher benutzt, um "verkindlicht" über die Sache zu sprechen. In einem rational sachlichen Gespräch, ist dieser Ausdruck, finde ich, nicht angebracht.

Comment: @userunknown: Dass der Ausdruck verklemmt ist, finde ich auch, aber da es anscheinend nur ordinäre/vulgäre oder übermäßig hochgestochene Begriffe gibt ist dies meiner Meinung nach der *am besten geeignete Ausdruck* (auch wenn das nicht bedeutet, dass er gut ist).

Comment: @jera: Hier ging es nicht um ein rational sachliches Gespräch, sonst würde ja wahrscheinlich ein eher "hochgestochener" Begriff gewählt werden. Für die Beispielsätze finde ich "Liebe machen" von den genannten Möglichkeiten die beste, wenn auch keine gute.

Comment: @BenSower ja, das ist mir schon bewusst, ich woltle es allerdings noch anmerken. Auch, weil ich gerade für den letzten Satz _Liebe machen_ nicht gut finde. "In einer durchschnittlichen Beziehung wird x-mal pro Monat Liebe gemacht."

Comment: Ja, ich gehe auch davon aus, dass es keine Lösung gibt, die alle Anforderungen und Beispiele erfüllen kann. Die Frage ist also eher ein Optimierungs-/Annäherungsproblem.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist keine eigentliche Antwort auf meine eigene Frage, aber die Häufigkeit mag einen gewissen Hinweis auf die Akzeptanz geben.

### Derewo

Unten aufgeführt ist die Position der einteiligen Verben im [Derewo-Korpus mit ca. 327 000 Grundformen](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html).

Ganz oben stehen Verben, die auch (und vor allem) eine nicht sexuelle Bedeutung haben. Übrigens kommen *budern* und *schnackseln* darin nicht vor, dafür aber *beischlafen* und sogar *minnen*. Zusammensetzungen wie *durchknallen* (Position 66 219), *verficken, verpoppen, herumvögeln, durchficken* und *rumficken* (alle jenseits 235 000) habe ich nicht mit aufgenommen.

```
  4 826. verkehren
  6 113. knacken
  7 830. knallen
  8 860. klarmachen
 18 288. nageln
 24 460. poppen
 27 780. knattern
 29 459. vögeln
 31 557. ficken
 35 529. bürsten
 50 373. vernaschen
 62 674. pudern
 65 546. kopulieren
 73 081. bumsen
 73 493. rammeln
 94 143. begatten
 99 977. bimsen
114 900. flachlegen
120 093. minnen
175 666. beschlafen
209 318. zwirnen
219 479. pimpern
251 518. koitieren
276 110. beischlafen
291 530. kohabitieren
```

### Google Ngram Viewer

Um auch einen historischen Überblick zu bekommen, habe ich die halbwegs unzweideutigen Verben auch im [Bücherkorpus von Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poppen%2Cv%C3%B6geln%2Cficken%2Cbegatten%2Cflachlegen%2Cvernaschen%2Cbumsen%2Bbimsen%2Crammeln%2Cminnen%2Cbeschlafen%2Bbeischlafen%2Cpimpern%2Ckopulieren%2Bkoitieren%2Bkohabitieren&year_start=1808&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) suchen lassen. Da nur maximal 12 Linien gleichzeitig dargestellt werden, habe ich einige Verben zusammengefasst.

Ein Ergebnis dieses groben Vergleichs ist, dass *begatten* bis ins 19. Jahrhundert deutlich häufiger und (zumindest unter den heute noch gebräuchlichen) der bevorzugte (eindeutige einteilige) Begriff war. 
Zwischen 1820 und 1835 hatte *vögeln* eine Hochphase, von der ich nicht sagen kann, ob sie evtl. mit der Kleinschreibung des Plurals von *Vogel* oder einem ähnlichen Effekt zusammenhängt. 
Die hochsprachlichen Verben *ko-…-ieren* scheinen vor allem in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts in gedruckten Werken verbreitet gewesen zu sein. 
Die häufige Verwendung von *minnen*, das um 1940 und von 1965 bis 1985 sogar die Spitze übernimmt, hat mich sehr überrascht, denn selbst in der Bedeutung ‘lieben, anbeten’ schätze ich es als selten ein – ich vermute einen OCR-Fehler oder sehr aktive Literaturwissenschaftler/Mediävisten.
Interessanterweise taucht *ficken* erst Mitte der 1960er auf und übernimmt ab 1990 die klare Vorherrschaft vor *vögeln*.

Auch Google findet keine Treffer für die regionalen Begriffe *budern* und *schnackseln*. Dabei erinnere ich mich an ein Skandälchen in den 90ern, als eine damals wohl halbwegs bekannte (weil reiche) Bayerin etwas von „schnackselnden Negern“ faselte.

Es lässt sich auch nach Gruppen von n-Grammen suchen, aber die [Ergebnisse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nummer+schieben%2CLiebe+machen%2CSex+haben%2BSex+machen%2CEhe+vollziehen%2Cintim+werden%2Bintim+sein%2Ck%C3%B6rperlich+lieben%2CVerkehr+haben%2CGeschlechtsverkehr+_VERB_%2CBeischlaf+_VERB_%2Ces+treiben%2Bes+miteinander+treiben&year_start=1808&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) sind mit Vorsicht zu genießen (v.a. bzgl. `_VERB_`). Interessanterweise tauchen Wendungen mit *Geschlechtsverkehr* erst um 1880 signifikant auf, während *Verkehr haben* (mglw. in nicht sexueller Bedeutung) schon deutlich länger vorkommt. Die Zusammensetzungen mit *Sex* setzen etwas später ein als *ficken*, erstmals um 1970 und dann zunehmend ab 1985. Die [Zusammensetzungen mit *schlafen*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mit+*+schlafen%2Cmiteinander+schlafen%2Cficken%2Cv%C3%B6geln%2Cpoppen%2Cpimpern%2C%2Cbumsen%2Bbimsen%2Cbeschlafen%2Cbeischlafen%2CBeischlaf+_VERB_&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmit%20%2A%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmit%20ihr%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20ihm%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20mir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20dir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20ihnen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Frauen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20M%C3%A4nnern%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Ihnen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20jemandem%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Dir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiteinander%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cficken%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%B6geln%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoppen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpimpern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28bumsen%20%2B%20bimsen%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeschlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeischlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeischlaf%20_VERB_%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cmit%20*%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bmit%20ihr%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20ihm%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20mir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20dir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20ihnen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Frauen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20M%C3%A4nnern%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Ihnen%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20jemandem%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmit%20Dir%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiteinander%20schlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cficken%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%B6geln%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoppen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpimpern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(bumsen%20%2B%20bimsen)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeschlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeischlafen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeischlaf%20_VERB_%3B%2Cc0) sind ebenfalls sehr frequent.

Man beachte, dass ich bei Google Ngrams nicht nach flektierten Formen gesucht habe. (Das Suffix `_INF_` kann nur einmal pro Anfrage verwendet werden.)

Comment: Ich habe mal die Belege für _minnen_ überflogen; so weit ich sehe, sind das alles mittelhochdeutsche Zitate (wo es dann auch kein Verb ist), und eine Reihe von schwedischen Ergebnissen hat sich auch hineingemogelt (_minnen_ = _Erinnerungen_).

Comment: Dieses Beispiel lässt mich wieder einmal sowohl an der Aussagekraft rein quantitativer Statistiken, als auch an der Repräsentativität der zugrundeliegenden Korpora zweifeln: Einige Ausdrücke in der Liste haben eine andere Hauptbedeutung, einige habe ich noch nie in diesem Zusammenhang gehört, regionale/soziale/"textsortenbedingte" Unterschiede sind nicht ersichtlich, morphologische/phone(ma)tische Varianten sind nicht einheitlich behandelt, Quantität sagt zumindest hier nichts über Qualität aus...